# Would Saitama resume Training, If he was defeated in battle, in future?

Tags: one-punch-man

In order to become strong, Saitama went through one year of hard training. So i think, until he is defeated, he will not start Training again.

Is there any chance saitama be defeated in future, in the anime (one punch man). Up until now, Saitama has faced many powerful enemies and Just one blow has finished everyone up?

As the anime name suggests (One Punch Man), Will Saitama remain this powerful in entire anime series.

Isn't Monster's association head a perfect match for saitama strength? Even in the manga, he defeated silver fang's student, with ease. Although Garou swiped all the Hero's Association?

Will saitama ever be defeated by anyone throughout this anime?

Comment: There's no way to predict the future but if you're talking about Season 1, then no, he is never defeated.

Comment: This question tries to suggest a theory of defeat of Saitama. I have watched manga upto 48 chapter, as he is as powerful as he was in season one. And if by any means, this question can be made more better, do suggest an edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saitama was defeated in the first season of the anime.

He engaged in an eating contest against Genos and lost by a large margin.

He has never been defeated in combat in the anime or manga to date.

Comment: Thank you @kaine, I meant Is there any possibility, that saitama will be defeated in future, so that he resumes his training again, since when he became strong, he stopped his training

Comment: @Syed I think we all understood the question. Unfortunately, speculative questions and answers are not permitted on stack exchange sites (besides worldbuilding I guess). They are considered to be a poor fit for the medium. That is why your question was closed.

Comment: i guess so, although i asked out of curiosity, but i think justice was served. Thanks anywat